# Codeigniter - can't hit a method in a class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my first CI project so forgive me.

I simply can't hit a method with an AJAX call. It keeps coming up as a 404 in Web Inspector.

I have a controller called "home.php".  It's working. I can land on my home page.

Then I have this AJAX call firing on a hover event

```
function showDataWindow(){
    // i might switch this to data attr, but for now item IDs are contained in class
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var thisIDpos = thisClass.indexOf("id-")+3;
    var thisID = thisClass.substr(thisIDpos, 3);
    alert(thisID); // alerting correctly
    $.post('getMoreInfo', { ID: thisID},
        function(data) {
             .. act on data
```

I simply can find the method I am calling - getMoreInfo.  Always 404.

I have a home.php class in my controllers and its set as my default, and it works because I am landing on my home page and getting the index.  But in that home controller is also my getMoreInfo function...

```
public function getMoreInfo()
{
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    $this->load->model('Artist_model');
    $assocReturned = $this->Artist_model->get_more_info($ID);
    echo json_encode($assocReturned);
}
```

And I feel like there is a tiny MC Hammer guarding that function.  "You can't touch this".  He mocks me in his little parachute pants and minuscule fade.

I think it must be how I am doing my URI in the Jquery AJAX post?  I have index re-writing in my htaccess (which I am kind of foggy on exactly)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

But I have tried just about every URI permutation in that AJAX call

```
www.mySite.com/index.php/home/getMoreInfo
index.php/home/getMoreInfo
index.php/getMoreInfo
/home/getMoreInfo
home/getMoreInfo
/getMoreInfo
getMoreInfo
```

!

And none have worked.

Comment: Everything you've shown above looks correct. What do you have in your `application/config/routes.php` file?

Comment: Should be: /home/getMoreInfo from what I read. Have you tried just that and checked the output?

Comment: @jtheman  Thanks for giving what it looked like the URI should be.. but I tried ( received POST http://mySite.com/home/getMoreInfo 404 (Not Found)  )

Comment: @swatkinsMy routes.php is really bare >> 
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: You must be having some sort of routing problem. Try remove your htaccess file and instead try accessing the URI: /index.php/home/getMoreInfo - also use CI's $this->input->post() instead of $_POST[] since CI escapes the input for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to call depends on how your router is configured.

Default call would be `/home/getMoreInfo`, but could be changed if you have reconfigured your router. Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I read that already and it's not as clear as it could be.  The example they give right up top is "example.com/class/function/id/".  But you dont actually need to use that in your code.  "/class/function" for ex.  Or what happens if you set your default controller.. can you just call "/method" and it would be routed to default?  It doesn't really just spell this stuff out.  But regardless.. I have "home.php" set as default.  and think "home/getMoreInfo" should work according to what I have read.  But it don't.

Comment: If you do **not** reconfigure the router, default is `/controller/action` in your case /home/getMoreInfo. getMoreInfo needs to be a public function in your home controller.

Comment: You could just type in /home/getMoreInfo in your browser and see what response you get.

Comment: getMoreInfo *is* a method in home.php.  And (I think) the fact that I am able to land on the page and the index function works means that the code is good in the whole class.. getMoreInfo is there. ......  But I just typed /home/getMoreInfo and got "This webpage is not found". ...  I dont get your suggestion of just typing into the browser bar?  For ex. I if I just type "mail" (which *is* a controller that I took direct access refusal *off* for testing) , I cant hit that either.  I thought I always had to use mySite.com , or mySite.com/controller?

Comment: the default action in CI is `index` So if you type /mail in your browser method index() is called in the controller mail. Home does not need to be a method in the home controller, unless you want to call /home/home

Comment: I'm either completely thick or I'm misunderstanding you (lets leave out that I'm on Chrome and when I type "mail" into my browser I get a Google search for it) .. but if I just type "mail" into my browser, how does it know I want "www.thisSite.com/mail" and not "www.thatSite.com/mail"? And I understand that default index function.. I have my default controller set to "home.php" in routes.php .. so mySite.com should hit index in home.php .. but mySite.com/getMoreInfo < this confuses me. How does it know if I want a method in default controller or a new controller altogether.. or it checks both?

Comment: Of course you need to type in the domain name before testing in chrome. So typing in www.yoursite.com/home in chrome calls method index() in your home controller. If you have set the default controller to `home` and typing in www.yoursite.com will call method index() in the home controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand what you've said, and I have read the guide and I am using what I believe is the right URI "/getMoreInfo" .. which should hit that function on the class I have set as default (home.php).  And I have the function there, and no luck.  But thanks for expanding my knowledge.  Last question?  Does CI check the default class and then it looks for another controller?  "/methodInDefaultClass" and "/differentClass" look the same, right?

Comment: CI (and most other MVC frameworks) check the url against the route. If a route cannot be found, or the method in the controller does not exists, or the controller does not exists, then a 404 page is shown. So if you type in your browser www.mysite.com/nonexistantcontroller or wwww.mysite.com/existingcontroller/nonexistingmethod a 404 page comes up.